# What is the purpose of `await TaskScheduler.Default` where the result isn't used?

Tags: .net, async-await, task-parallel-library, vsix

I have a block of code that's roughly like:

```cs
async Task Initialize(){
   await TaskScheduler.Default;
   var service = await CreateServiceAsync();
   await TaskScheduler.Default;
   var status = await service.CheckStatusAsync();  
   // ...
}
```

What purpose does awaiting `TaskScheduler.Default` serve if we're not using the task scheduler to schedule anything?  What might I break if I remove them?

This is in the startup code for a Visual Studio Extension (VSIX) project.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Normally, task schedulers cannot be `await`ed. However, the VS SDK does have some [extensions that allow awaiting task schedulers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.threading.awaitextensions.getawaiter?view=visualstudiosdk-2022#microsoft-visualstudio-threading-awaitextensions-getawaiter(system-threading-tasks-taskscheduler)). According to the docs, they are used as "switching" calls so that the `async` method just resumes executing on the specified `TaskScheduler`.

`TaskScheduler.Default` uses the thread pool for continuations, so `await TaskScheduler.Default` will change to a thread pool thread for the remainder of the method.

Personally, I don't like "switching" methods, primarily because it's possible to *not know* what context you're in, e.g., in a `catch` block. I prefer using `Task.Run` to explicitly scope the work that is done on the thread pool.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Though I'm still confused. My understanding now is: the goal is to get the work into the thread pool. ie, not the UI thread (because it's in the Package Startup code and we needed the UI thread for MEF), yes? I thought awaiting something meant that the awaited code would be ran in any unknown context. Then... the code above is just trying to be extra certain that the UI *thread* is 100% free for other things? Namely, I could wrap everything relating to the service in a `Task.Run`, remove the task scheduler parts, and the result would be similar? Why would one be better?

Comment: I have a [blog post](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) that describes how `await` and contexts work. The code ensures that `CreateServiceAsync` is invoked on a thread pool thread. Without the switch, `CreateServiceAsync` would be invoked on the UI thread. I prefer `Task.Run` instead because the thread pool code is scoped.